# How to lookup in python between 2 dataframes with match mode -> an exact match or the next larger item?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to create a lookup (similar to excel for example) with match mode -> an exact match or the next larger item.

Let's say I have these 2 dataframes:

```
seed(1)
np.random.seed(1) 
Wins_Range = np.arange(1,101,1)
Wins = pd.DataFrame({"Wins Needed": Wins_Range})

Wins


    Wins Needed
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
... ...
95  96
96  97
97  98
98  99
99  100
```

And the second one:

```
Levels_Range = np.arange(1,101,1)
Levels = pd.DataFrame({"Level": Levels_Range})
Levels["Wins"]=np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5],size=len(Levels), p=[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]).cumsum()

Levels

    Level   Wins
0   1   3
1   2   7
2   3   8
3   4   10
4   5   11
... ... ...
95  96  281
96  97  286
97  98  289
98  99  290
99  100 294
```

Now, I'd like to pull the level from Levels df to the Wins df when the condition is Wins Needed=Wins but as I said - the match mode will be an exact match or the next larger item.
BTW - the type of Levels["Wins"] is float and the type of Wins["Win"] is int if that matters.

I've tried to use the merge function but it doesn't work (I'm new at python) -

Wins.merge(Levels, on='Wins Needed', how='left')

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
out = pd.merge_asof(Wins, Levels, left_on='Wins Needed', right_on='Wins',
                    direction='forward')[['Wins Needed', 'Level']]
```

Or

```
Wins['Level'] = pd.merge_asof(Wins, Levels, left_on='Wins Needed', right_on='Wins',
                              direction='forward')['Level']
```

*NB. the keys must be sorted for a `merge_asof`.*

Output:

```
    Wins Needed  Level
0             1      1
1             2      1
2             3      1
3             4      2
4             5      2
..          ...    ...
95           96     35
96           97     35
97           98     36
98           99     36
99          100     37

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

If the values are not initially sorted:

```
Wins['Level'] = pd.merge_asof(Wins[['Wins Needed']].reset_index().sort_values(by='Wins Needed'),
                              Levels.sort_values(by='Wins'),
                              left_on='Wins Needed', right_on='Wins',
                              direction='forward').set_index('index')['Level']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are you familiar with another solution when the keys don't need to be sorted?

Comment: @Naor reset_index, sort_keys, merge, restore index. Otherwise, there is no direct way ;)